# HTML textbox which takes multiple values by autofill like Facebook, Google+ etc

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need help on creating a text box as it is in the Facebook send new message feature. I mean in the To field of this message box, we can add as many people as we want and all these people are suggested from our friend list and we can add as many people as we want.

I want to create same feature for my website in which we can add multiple values in our text fields, all of which are treated as different values and the rest processing task is done.

Comment: Something like this ? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: This question demonstrates no attempt to research or solve the problem. Please read the help section on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery UI Autocomplete :

Try this code

**Script**

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
function split( val ) {
return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
return split( term ).pop();
}
$( "#tags" )
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
$( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
event.preventDefault();
}
})
.autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: function( request, response ) {
// delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
},
focus: function() {
// prevent value inserted on focus
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
var terms = split( this.value );
// remove the current input
terms.pop();
// add the selected item
terms.push( ui.item.value );
// add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
terms.push( "" );
this.value = terms.join( ", " );
return false;
}
});
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbbx2/)

Comment: What if we have to use dropdown suggestions from a mysql table by PHP instead of your availableTags variable?

Comment: you have to fetch array and store it on variable,replace hardcoded value with your array

Comment: but that is a PHP script... how can I add it in a javascript function???